# Paginated Vertical Scroll WatchKit

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-4

Does anyone know how to achieve this scrollable table with the pagination and animation?

Calendar App:

[image: Calendar app]

Workout App:

[image: Workout app]

If I have a paginated table each ‘view’ is the size of the screen, not like the previous images. I have tried so by doing something like this:

```
      WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["View1", "View2", "View3", "View4"], contexts: nil, orientation: .vertical, pageIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I am looking to do the same and not using swift.

Answer (score 3):

In watchOS 6 with SwiftUI, you can do this by creating a [list](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) with the carousel list style.

Comment: How about non-SwiftUI?

Comment: @GlennPosadas have you figured this out yet? I am stuck there too

Comment: Yep. I had to use SwiftUI together with WatchKit. This type of list is ONLY available in SwiftUI.

Comment: Correct. And at this point, WatchKit Storyboards are deprecated so realistically you have to move to SwiftUI.